# Browser highlight support for my very own protocol handler

Tags: cross-browser, browser-extension, protocol-handler, uri-scheme

I'm using a class to register my protocol, lets say `lorem:` to operating system. Its working perfect but I would like to do couple of things.

I want to create something like [Skype Click to Call](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/click-to-call/). People will share uri's like `lorem://12345678` and when others click this the event handler will redirect that request to my windows application. I want to make this uri clickable. How can identify this new scheme to browsers so when a page contains `lorem://12345678`, browser will transform it something like
`<a href="lorem://12345678">lorem://12345678</a>` and users be able to click it.

Can I do it with browser configuration or should I write some kind of extension to implement this rule. It must support all browsers so is that means I need to write same extension for Chrome, Firefox and IE? And how can I install all extensions with my software setup?

**Straight to point question:** I want to transform `lorem://ipsum` text to `<a href="lorem://ipsum">My URL!</a>` on most popular browsers

Answer (score 1):

as i understood -- you need to write extensions for each browser, check out this question:
[how do I create my own URL protocol? (e.g. so://...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389204/how-do-i-create-my-own-url-protocol-e-g-so)

and this is an example of browser approach:
[Custom protocol handler in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087728/custom-protocol-handler-in-chrome)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
When I write lorem://test it works already. I also want to allow people to click lorem://test on their browsers. I found http://goo.gl/k6R8o8 but its about html5 and it requires <a> tag to work. Since I already registered that protocol on system level, its not what I actually want. I've updated question to make it clear.