# Where to call navigator.registerProtocolHandler?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, custom-protocol, protocol-handler

**How and where do I use navigator.registerProtocolHandler to make it work?**

.

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087728/custom-protocol-handler-in-chrome) suggests you can call the following function to add the custom protocol handler:

```
navigator.registerProtocolHandler('web+custom', 'http://example.com/rph?q=%s', 'My App');
```

When I call it from the console, I get the

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'registerProtocolHandler' on 'Navigator': 
Can only register custom handler in the document's origin.
```

This also happens if I include it as a part of a content script as suggested [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web-based_protocol_handlers)

**install_protocol.html**

```
<head>
  <title>Web Protocol Handler Sample - Register</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    navigator.registerProtocolHandler("burger",
                              "http://www.google.co.uk/?uri=%s",
                              "Burger handler");
  </script>
</head>
```

I also tried calling it in my *background.js* script, where it didn't give the error, however the protocol doesn't seem to respond.

.

Could you explain how to go through the process of registering and using a custom protocol in Chrome?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to register handler with URL `http://www.google.co.uk…` then your script (the one, that calls `navigator.registerProtocolHanlder`) must be loaded from the same domain, that is `www.google.co.uk`.

Comment: I tried running the following line in the browser address bar
     javascript:navigator.registerProtocolHandler("web+custom","https: //www.google.co.uk", "myApp") 

and I got a following syntax error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'registerProtocolHandler' on 'Navigator': The url provided ('https://www.google.co.uk') does not contain '%s'

Comment: @Voy the %s is the substitution parameter, it will inject the bit after the colon e.g 'whatever' from customhandler:whatever into the url

Comment: This is correct, but to clarify further, to make this work - to add the handler it has to be run from the console while you are looking at the url which will be handling - http://www.google.co.uk in this case.

Comment: U are the hero of my day. Thanks man, saved me a lot of work ✌