# Setting non-http/https location.href?

Tags: javascript

How can I do something like this?

```
window.location.href="mycustomHREF://interceptMe?msg=helpMe";
```

I'd like to set the window location to a dummy url for a local app to intercept

Comment: Custom URL Protocol Handlers, E.g. [How do I register a custom URL protocol in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows)

Comment: It depends on the browser and if it's aware of the protocol, this may be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087728/custom-protocol-handler-in-chrome