# Can I fire up a Chrome extension API from code?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to launch a Google Chrome extension within a website? E.g run some javascript that will launch the extensions UI?

I'm building a web-app that will allow users to take screenshots of their desktop and edit them. I've got a sample extension up and running using [dektopCapture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture) but it is an 'app' style of an extension.

- It allows to select a window to stream from, then take a
  snapshot within the extension UI(using a button) that is saved as an image string

---

**My question is:**

Is it possible to fire up the desktopCapture UI (the window that gets the available windows to stream from), from within my web-app, maybe a button, take the stream and place it on a canvas/HTML5 video element within my web-app?

I'm figuring that I could hook-up an event-listener within the extension and use [runtime.onMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) to post a message from within my app

**Notes**:

If there's a more intuitive way to do this, I can go that route - e.g If I could keep as much interaction *within* the web-app with just the extension running in the background, that would be even better.

The extension is of type `browser_action` but I want it to be applicable to a single page(the app's webpage) so if it can be used in a `page_action` I'd prefer that instead. There's really no need to have browser_action icon if I can trigger this from within a webpage

I'm also planning to build a FF extension so any insights there are also appreciated.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087728/custom-protocol-handler-in-chrome

Comment: @VasiliyVanchuk That seems to be dealing with sending messages back and forth

Comment: thus you can't garantee that user has your extention - pobable buble events up - better way

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Is this a page_action? If so, I haven't found a way to programmatically launch those

Comment: sending message seems the only way. in this way you should own both the website javascript and the extension javascript. a message sender and a message listener.

Comment: @RGraham `externally_connectables` allows you to do just that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm answering my own question.

I've managed to get it working using [externally_connectables](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/externally_connectable).

> The externally_connectable manifest property declares which
>   extensions, apps, and web pages can connect to your extension via
>   runtime.connect and runtime.sendMessage.

#### 1. Declare app/webpage in manifest.json

Just declare your web-app/page within your `manifest.json` as an `externally_connectable`.

E.g I wanted to connect my app is hosted on Github Pages and I have a domain name of *https://nicholaswmin.github.io*, so it does a bit like this:

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["https://nicholaswmin.github.io/*"]
}, //rest of manifest.json
```

#### 2. Set up event listener for messages in background.js

Then set up an event listener in your `background.js` like so:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
 //Stuff you want to run goes here, even desktopCapture calls
});
```

#### 3. Send message from your web/app page

And call it from within your web-app/website like this:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("APP ID GOES HERE", 
                       {data: { key : "capture"}});
```

Make sure that your website is correctly declared as an `externally_connectable` in your `manifest.json` and that you are passing the app-id when sending the message

Comment: Hello!

I was wondering where I can get the app id? I'm working with reactjs and its got its own manifest.json that has name in it.