# Generating a shortcut or launching a program with arguments from a web browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, shortcut-file

First, before people start yelling about "This isn't secure!!!", I am asking in regards to a **private, business intranet site** that is not publicly accessible over the Internet. We are in control of all of the systems and workstations.

Our users would like the ability to somehow launch a program from a web browser if installed on a user's computer. One example is, if there is a web interface that displays a SQL server IP address and a database name, be able to click a link and open SQL Server Management Studio on the workstation via the command line arguments to `ssms.exe`. Or being able to launch Visual Studio and invoke the `/diff` command line option which compares two files.

I understand this goes against all manner of web security, but is there any way that this could work out of the box (or via a Chrome extension)?

The intranet site is written in ASP.NET 4, though we're considering upgrading to ASP.NET Core 2.0 if that makes a difference.

Comment: What you're looking for is custom protocol handlers.  This question is relevant:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087728/custom-protocol-handler-in-chrome

Comment: So it looks like, at a bare minimum, this would be a registry change to create a new protocol, which launches the respective desktop application? Am I reading that correctly? If you type this up as an answer here with examples, I'll gladly accept that as the answer if it ends up working for us.