# How can I use a link on my website to open an application?

Tags: web, web-applications, web-deployment

what programming languages do I need to know to make app.mywebsite.com to be an app that I want to use. I own mywebsite.com for ex and i want when I go to app.mywebsite.com to open an ann I created. Like a desktop app, for room booking and management that is.
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean opening a desktop application in response to a web page, you can use a [custom application protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37601807/6625815) but that is browser- and OS-specific.

Comment: I would like to be opened from any web browser. I don't mind if it's only for windows for ex but to be able to be opened from any browser.

Comment: [Here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol) is a tutorial for registering a similar protocol for Firefox. At the end of the day, it will always be browser specific.  [This](https://caniuse.com/#feat=registerprotocolhandler) page has support details for various browsers.