# Execute a shell (script) from Chromium?

Tags: linux, chromium

Is there a way to launch a bash/ksh shell, or execute a shell script from Chromium? Is there a setting to tweak, a plungin to add, a workaround besides php and a local server?

Sorry if this is a duplicate.  I assumed I would find an answer here, but only see answers about launching Chromium using a script or complete workarounds avoiding my question, with a local server and JavaScript/PHP.  I have an Apache server available and can do the coding, but rather not.

I could do this in Internet Explorer on Windows (or used to be able to launch a .bat script there. I haven't used IE in a long time), why not in Chromium on Linux?

I understand the security concerns and sandbox in the browser, but in this case the browser never goes outside a firewall and I just want to launch a script from Chromium.

Thank you for your thoughtful replies.

Comment: You can use a [custom protocol handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37601807/1899640). This is how Steam, Spotify and such let you execute their application via the browser.

Comment: That something used to be possible in IE is not a compelling argument that that thing should be possible today. IE used to be full of major, exploitable security bugs.