# Force a link to open in Chrome when sent via Outlook

Tags: html, google-chrome, outlook

We have a report that we make in HTML that we need to email to a client via Outlook.

The client's default browser is IE11, however the HTML file currently only works in Chrome. They've specifically asked us to figure out a way to open the file by default in Chrome, without having the client go in and change their default browser manually.

That is, they don't want to change their default browser from IE, however whenever we send this HTML, they want to have it open automatically in Chrome.

Is it possible to embed code into the HTML that forces the link to open in Chrome, despite IE being the default browser?

[This seemed promising](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142834/creating-a-url-that-always-opens-in-chrome/142844), but it's not working in Outlook.

Comment: What if they don't have chrome installed? Really, your best bet is to tell them to open it in chrome.

Comment: On a personal note, a link that behaves like this would drive me crazy and make me angry at a vendor.

Comment: We know they have chrome installed. That isn't the issue. As it is now, they have to pull the HTML file into their local machine, then open it in chrome. They understand the limitations and asked for this feature specifically.

Answer (score 0):

The best what you can do is to register a custom URI handler for your emails. The [Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)) page in MSDN describes how to develop handlers for Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) schemes. For example, here is how it may look in the message body:

```
<a href="mycustproto:Hello World">Click Me</a>
```

Also, take a look at the similar page - [Custom protocol handler in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087728/custom-protocol-handler-in-chrome).