# Zabbix Run a script to call Exe from my local computer

Tags: zabbix

I have some computers and all have RDP enabled. So Id like to link to create a script to call a command from my local computer, like "C:\Windows\system32\mstsc.exe {HOST.CONN}"
but i dont know how to call a .exe from my own computer.
Is this possible?

[how i imagine add rdp option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xckUN.png)

Answer (score -1):

It's an useful idea, but Zabbix is not quite there yet. You would need to use a URL field, but there is no URL field in the Host, only in the Problem. You also need a [Custom protocol handler in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087728/custom-protocol-handler-in-chrome) (or your favourite browser, almost same procedure).

To add an URL field in the menù you highlighted, you may use [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=it) (client side) or fiddle with the zabbix-web source code (server side). I'd use TamperMonkey because editing the source code will not survive a package upgrade.