# How to run .bat file or .exe file from browser using html java script / angular/react and it should support in all browser

Tags: angular, batch-file, exe

I have one batch file in my local,I want to run it from browser

For example I have one html page with anchor tag If I click on that link then it should run a batchfile provided in href attribute.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could register a [custom protocol handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087728/custom-protocol-handler-in-chrome)

Comment: For obvious reasons you can't just run an executable on someone else's computer. You could provide the batch file as a download, and let the user decide if they want to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

Web browsers run JavaScript code in a "sandbox", specifically to prevent exactly what you want to do, because it's an enormous security risk.

In short, you shouldn't, and can't do that.