# Check if a string contains nothing but an URL in PHP

Tags: php, url, validation

I am wondering if this is a proper way to check, if a string contains nothing but an URL:

```
if (stripos($string, 'http') == 0 && !preg_match('/\s/',$string)) {
  do_something();
}
```

stripos() checks if the string starts with "http"
preg_match() checks if the string contains spaces

If not so, I assume that the string is nothing but an URL - but is that assumption valid? Are there better ways to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [the best way to check if a url is valid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058578/the-best-way-to-check-if-a-url-is-valid)

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Use [`filter_var()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

```
if (filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) { 
  // you're good
}
```

The filters can be even more refined. [See the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) for more on this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! (I think both answers came at the same time)

Comment: Thanks, this is better than parse_url($string), because anything with a colon (:) would get dinged as a url. Works alot better. Wish there was a way to detect if it was a url even if it did not have the http:// though.

Comment: This failed to successfully validate a URL where I had the chracter `å` in it - but the URL was working. (Using PHP 7.0)

Comment: This FAILED to validate valid URLs where they contain % chracters

Answer (score 10):

In PHP there is a better way to validate the URL:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

```
if(filter_var('http://example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    echo 'this is URL';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To more securely validate URLs (and those 'non-ascii' ones), you can

1. Check with the filter (be sure to check the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) on which filter suits your situation)
2. Check to see if there are DNS records

   ```
   $string = idn_to_ascii($URL);
   if(filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) && checkdnsrr($string, "A")){
       // you have a valid URL
   }
   ```