# These code always prompt invalid path file. I dont have any idea why :/

Tags: php, download

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['sportname'])){ 
    include("connect.php");
    $name = $_POST['sportname'];
    $sql = "Select docs From tbl_sport WHERE sprt_name= '".$name."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row=mysql_fetch_object($result);
    $file = $row->docs; 


    ini_set("allow-url-fopen", true);
    // Fetch the file info.
    $filePath = 'http://prisaa-region11.com/Docs/'.$file;

    if(file_exists($filePath)) {
        $fileName = basename($filePath);
        $fileSize = filesize($filePath);

        // Output headers.
        header("Cache-Control: private");
        header("Content-Type: application/stream");
        header("Content-Length: ".$fileSize);
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileDisplayName);

        // Output file.
        readfile ($filePath);                   
        exit();
    }
    else {
        die('The provided file path is not valid.');
    }
}       
?>
```

i dont know whats wrong with the path

Comment: `file_exists` can only be used for protocols that support `stat()`, and `http` doesn't.

Comment: should i just change it to "Docs/.$file" ?

Comment: That will look for a file on the local server, not a URL. If that's what you want, then that's what you should change it tod.

Comment: hmm. I already put this on a hosted site. I dont know what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [Filter Validator](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php)

```
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE) {
    die('Not a valid URL');
}
```

Check this similar thread
[Best way to check if a URL is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058578/the-best-way-to-check-if-a-url-is-valid)