# Check url format using php not work

Tags: php

When `$url_xxx = www.googlecom` or `http://www.5555testetstcom` or `http://wwwgooglecom` it's will echo `OK` WHY ?

```
<?PHP
$url_xxx = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_mysqli,$_POST['url_xxx']);
if(!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$url_xxx))
{
    echo "URL incorrect format";
}
else
{
    echo "OK";
}
?>
```

Comment: Because your regex is invalid?  Why would you be checking for `[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]` in a host?

Comment: How about using parse_url `http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php` to check the parts of the url. Then check only the parts with regex if needed.

Comment: could you please show me for example ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Regex is badly shaped. You can decompose it in three parts;

1. \b(?:(?:https?|ftp)://|www.)   (Starts with http or https or such)
2. [-a-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*  (Any character)
3. [-a-z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]    (Any character)

Your expression reads "Anything starting with {1}, followed by {2} that can appear from 0 to many times, followed by {3} (which is anything)"

So, well, as {2} is optional due the * modifier, it finally reads like "Anything starting with http:// and followed by anything matches

First I would recommend using Rubular to check your Regex when you build them, it's a REALLY helpful website http://rubular.com . If you would want to fix the regex you should at least require some dots in the middle.

Second, for this particular case you should check this response by Gordon in
[Best way to check if a URL is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058578/best-way-to-check-if-a-url-is-valid)

Which snipped from there the response is:

```
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE) {
    die('Not a valid URL');
}
```

Comment: Still echo Yes on this string. Why ? `<?php
$url = "http://wwwgoogle.com";
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE) 
{
    echo "NO";
}
else
{
    echo "YES";
}
?>`